# What does ‘justness’ mean in the following (literary) examples?

Tags: meaning

Examples from the internet:

- "A conceit is a comparison whose ingenuity is more striking than its **justness**..." (Helen Gardner on Metaphysical poetry)
- "In poetry, they must be allowed to excel all other mortals; wherein the **justness** of their similes, and the minuteness as well as exactness of their descriptions, are indeed inimitable."
- "The purity of his style, the delicacy of his turns, and the **justness** of his characters..."

I think the following definition of the word makes sense in the context of literature: *conformity with some esthetic standard of correctness or propriety*. But I don't fully understand the definition or how it applies to comparisons, similes, and fictional characters.

Comment: The most common meaning today is probably EITHER ***justness = rightfulness, lawfulness; fairness; validity, soundness, justifiableness*** OR ***righteousness; uprightness, integrity***. But an older and less common sense is ***exactness, precision, accuracy***. You can look up those definitions yourself (I've listed "synonyms" from the three "subdefinitions" in the full OED), and it's really ***up to you*** to decide which *specific* definition applies in any given case. That's mostly a matter of *opinion + context* rather than the inherent "meaning" of the word.

Comment: (In ***my*** opinion, "justness" of *characters* will probably refer to their "righteousness, integrity", but with *comparisons* and *similes* it'll be a matter of "exactness, accuracy".)

Comment: In these examples: _fitness_ / _appropriateness_ / '_well-drawnness_'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OED has

**Justness**

> **3. The quality or state of being right, proper, or correct; conformity to truth or to a required or agreed standard; correctness in amount, proportion, aesthetic quality, etc. Also: exactness, precision, accuracy.** *Now somewhat rare.*
>
> 1832   Compar. Coincidence Reason & Script. I. viii. 311   *The following considerations appear to us powerfully supportive of the justness of the foregoing answer to our fourth and last question.*
>
> 1876   M. Arnold Lit. & Dogma (ed. 5) Pref. p. xxiv   *After we have got all the facts of our special study, justness of perception to deal with the facts is still required.*
>
> 2006   W. I. Miller Eye for Eye ii. 23   *One can never underestimate the basic moral and aesthetic justness of getting perfectly even.*

Thus **justness** of comparisons similes, and fictional characters, indicates that the comparisons, similes, and fictional characters are finely crafted so as to be objectively **apt and accurate** in the context and serve a complementary role in the literature as a whole.

Comment: The justness of this answer refutes the opinions of the question closers.

Comment: Thank you so much! I definitely see how similes and comparisons can be apt, but the idea of a character’s aptness is puzzling to me.

Comment: @user392289 *the idea of a character’s aptness is puzzling to me.* That is genuinely a question for the Literature forum: I would only comment that certain characters in literature are very well written and are exactly what the narrative required.